# Can't use Lyrics slash command, I'm getting an "s." error

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
return Result.err(new CombinedError(errors));
                      ^

CombinedError: Received one or more errors
    at UnionValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1051:23)
    at UnionValidator.parse (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
    at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:228:20)
    at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/EmbedBuilder.js:22:18)
    at Object.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/commands/lyrics.js:33:12)
    at /home/shifty/bot-3/events/interactionCreate.js:62:26
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
  errors: [
    ExpectedValidationError: Expected values to be equals
        at LiteralValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:692:76)
        at LiteralValidator.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:92:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1046:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:228:20)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/EmbedBuilder.js:22:18)
        at Object.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/commands/lyrics.js:33:12)
        at /home/shifty/bot-3/events/interactionCreate.js:62:26
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      validator: 's.literal(V)',
      given: undefined,
      expected: null
    },
    ValidationError: Expected a number primitive
        at NumberValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:859:70)
        at NumberValidator.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:92:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1046:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:228:20)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/EmbedBuilder.js:22:18)
        at Object.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/commands/lyrics.js:33:12)
        at /home/shifty/bot-3/events/interactionCreate.js:62:26
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      validator: 's.number',
      given: undefined
    },
    ValidationError: Expected an array
        at TupleValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1682:25)
        at TupleValidator.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:92:23)
        at UnionValidator.handle (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:1046:32)
        at UnionValidator.parse (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@sapphire/shapeshift/dist/index.js:106:88)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/@discordjs/builders/dist/index.js:228:20)
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/EmbedBuilder.js:22:18)
        at Object.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/commands/lyrics.js:33:12)
        at /home/shifty/bot-3/events/interactionCreate.js:62:26
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      validator: 's.tuple(T)',
      given: undefined
    }
  ]
}
```

I made a Discord music bot and I made a lyric command for it and I'm getting this error

This is the error I get every time I run the lyrics command, it's an error I think occurs because the code itself is not correct?

in that case here's the lyric command's code:

```js
const { EmbedBuilder, ApplicationCommandOptionType } = require("discord.js");
const { get } = require("node-superfetch");
const config = require("../config.js");
const db = require("../mongoDB");

module.exports = {
  name: "lyrics",
  description: "Gets the lyrics of a song.",
  userPerms: [],
  player: true,
  dj: false,
  inVoiceChannel: true,
  sameVoiceChannel: true,
  options: [
    {
      name: "song",
      description: "Song name to return lyrics for.",
      type: ApplicationCommandOptionType.String,
      required: false,
    },
  ],

  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   * @param {CommandInteraction} interaction
   */

 run: async (client, interaction) => {
    await interaction.reply({
      embeds: [
        new EmbedBuilder()
          .setColor(client.embedColor)
          .setDescription(" **Searching...**"),
      ],
    });

    let player;
    if (client.manager) {
      player = client.manager.players.get(interaction.guild.id);
    } else {
      return interaction.reply({
        embeds: [
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("Red")
            .setDescription("Node not connected"),
        ],
      });
    }

    const args = interaction.options.getString("song");
    if (!args && !player) {
      return interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("Red")
            .setDescription("There's no music playing."),
        ],
      });
    }

    let search = args ? args : player.queue.current.title;
    let url = `https://api.darrennathanael.com/lyrics?song=${search}`;

    let lyrics = await get(url);

    if (!lyrics || lyrics.status !== 200) {
      return interaction.editReply({
        embeds: [
          new EmbedBuilder()
            .setColor("Red")
            .setDescription(
              `❌ | No lyrics found for ${search}!\nMake sure you entered your search correctly.`
            ),
        ],
      });
    }

    let text = lyrics.body.lyrics;
    let lyricsEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setColor(client.embedColor)
      .setTitle(`${lyrics.body.full_title}`)
      .setURL(lyrics.url)
      .setThumbnail(lyrics.body.thumbnail)
      .setDescription(text);

    if (text.length > 4096) {
      text = text.substring(0, 4090) + "[...]";
      lyricsEmbed
        .setDescription(text)
        .setFooter({ text: "Truncated, the lyrics were too long." });
    }

    return await interaction.editReply({ embeds: [lyricsEmbed] });
  },
};
```

I tried adding `const` to `new EmbedBuilder` which didn't work out

Answer (score 0):

The error says you are passing `undefined` when it expects something else. It's easy to read these errors if you know how.

```
ExpectedValidationError: Expected values to be equals
        -- internal files --
        at EmbedBuilder.setColor (/home/shifty/bot-3/node_modules/discord.js/src/structures/EmbedBuilder.js:22:18) -----> The function you called
        at Object.run (/home/shifty/bot-3/commands/lyrics.js:33:12) -----> Where the error occurs - your file
        at /home/shifty/bot-3/events/interactionCreate.js:62:26
        at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) {
      validator: 's.literal(V)', -----> What it expects
      given: undefined, -----> What you passed
      expected: null -----> More information on what it expects, if the validator is not clear enough
```

Since none of these matched, it throws the error. If you look on line 33 of lyrics.js, as said in the stack trace, you'll see `.setColor(client.embedColor)`. This means `client.embedColor` is undefined. It's not a native discord.js property, so I assume you either meant to set it, and failed to do so, or accessed the property incorrectly.